# symfony 2 - error 500 when loading resources with assetic in dev mode

Tags: symfony, caching, assetic

I'm having trouble with the inclusion of resources (js/css) generated with assetic in dev mode. I'm running the application in local with a mac (El capitan) and xampp webserver.

At every load, some resources goes casually in error 500. 
Sometimes the page goes totally in error 500.

I think it is a permission problem. Infact the problem seems to appear only when I flush the cache. I have run the following commands:

```
sudo chown -R daemon:daemon app/logs app/cache
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache app/logs
```

First refresh:

[image]

Second refresh:

[image]

Third refresh:

Everything goes normally.

Fourth refresh:

[image]

Comment: cache folder permissions can be tricky. Be sure to try all steps mentioned in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup

Comment: @jahller I ran the commands as described in the documentation you shared:

$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs

Comment: It seems to solve the problem, even if I flush the cache. I have to monitor the situation.